# Move focus from one Edit text box to another

Tags: android, focus

I am writing a simple calculator application(using absolute layout with 3 edit boxes and some buttons), which has two inputtext boxes and a output box.

```
input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
```

now once user enters some numerics into input1 and presses '+', now i want to shift the focus from input1 to input2. How can i do that?

I tried the below code on keypress of '+'

```
onClick(View arg0){
    operator.setText("+");

    //Move focus from input1 to input2
    input1.clearFocus();
    input2.setNextFocusDownId(input2.getId());
}
```

but this is not working.. can you please help me on this?

Comment: well, i found the answer, we can simply call 
input2.requestfocus();
to change the foucus.

Comment: What if you need to use this in TextWatcher, and you need to generalize it, which means you have not to use specific object to call requestFocus();
Do you have the answer for that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, I found the answer: we can simply call `input2.requestFocus();` to change the focus.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`input1.setNextFocusDownId(input2.getId());`

you are using input2, and I guess that you want to go from input1 to input2.

Answer (score 0):

[By the way, you want to avoid using AbsoluteLayout - it's deprecated, and may be removed.]

Instead of using onClick, you want the action to happen in a KeyListener's onKeyDown method.

See: [setKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener(android.text.method.KeyListener))

Then you can examine the [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)'s key with

```
KeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PLUS
```